# Django. Возвращает Page not found (404)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, url, views

Изучаю Django по книге Эрика Мэтиза "Изучаем Python". Не удается зайти на страничку с формой. Выдает

```
Not Found: /new_entry/1/
[05/Feb/2020 20:18:18] "GET /new_entry/1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2870
```

Я понимаю, что проблема в форме или в пути, но что именно понять не могу, так как по этому же принципу перед этим была добавлена первая форма.

```
Код learning_logs\urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    #Вывод домашней страницы
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    #Вывод всех тем
    path('topics/',views.topics, name='topics'),
    #Страница с информацией по выбранной теме
    #path('^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)', views.topic, name='topic'),
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
    #Страница для создания новой темы
    path('new_topic/',views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    #Страница для добавления новой информации
    path('new_entry/<int:topic_id>', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
]
```

Вьюхи learning_logs\views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Topic
from .forms import TopicForm,EntryForm

def index(request):
    """Домашняя страница проекта"""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

def topics(request):
    """Вывод всех тем"""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics':topics}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/topics.html',context)

def topic(request,topic_id):
    """Выводит одну тему и все ее записи"""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/topic.html',context)

def new_topic(request):
    """Определяет новую тему"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        #Данные не отправлялись, создается новая форма
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        #отправленны данные, обработать данные
        form =TopicForm(request.POST)
        #если форма проходит валидацию
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/new_topic.html',context)

def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Добавляет новую запись по конкретной теме"""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic',args=[topic_id]))
    context = {'topic':topic,'form':form}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/new_entry.html',context)
```

Шаблон, который отражается нормально и где есть ссылка на страницу с формой

learning_logs\templates\learning_logs\topic.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <p>Topic:{{ topic }}</p>
  <p>Entries</p>
  <p>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}/">add new entry</a>
  </p>
  <ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
      <li>{{entry.date_added|date:'M d,Y H:i' }}</li>
      <li>{{entry.text|linebreaks }}</li>
    {% empty %}
      <li>
        There are no entries for this topic yet.
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

Кликаем по ссылке и получаем Page not found (404)

И сама страница, которая не отражается

learning_logs\templates\learning_logs\new_entry.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <p><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>
  <p>Add a new entry:</p>
      <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}" method='post'>
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button name='submit'>add entry</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

По совету камрада, в файле url поменял путь 
Было

```
path('new_entry/<int:topic_id>', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
```

Стало

```
path('topics/<int:topic_id>/new_entry/', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
```

Но тут выплыла такая проблема. При запросе почему то добавляется лишний знак "/" и соответственно, страница становится недоступна. Но если убрать в адресной строке лишний слеш, то она начинает отражаться. Теперь вопрос - как убрать это лишнее добавление? Потому что если в path я убираю слеш, все равно происходит тоже - он добавляется и страница становится недоступна из за неверного адреса

Comment: Во втором `path` опечатка? Туда как-то `topics` попало.

Comment: @nomnoms12 нет, путь topics нужен для отражения всех тем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте `/` к концу пути в `urls.py`, а в шаблоне уберите.

***urls.py:***

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('new_entry/<int:topic_id>/', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
]  #                             ^^^
```

***topic.html:***

```html
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}">add new entry</a>
<!--                                                    ^^               -->
```

Comment: к сожалению нет. Я дополнил вопрос, потому что во время запроса в адресную строку вписывается лишний /

Comment: я добавил в описании проблемы развернуто. Проблема в том, что когда формируется запрос GET к адресу добавляется знак "/" и адрес становится некорректным и тогда пишет, что страница не найдена. Посмотрите пожалуйста дополнение

Comment: @славагудзенко Да, уже увидел. У Вас потому что в шаблоне `/`. Сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: стыдно то как, а я пол дня из за опечатки бьюсь. Спасибо)))